# windows.onload not calling function when accessing new page

Tags: javascript, iis, webforms, master-pages

Scenario: I have set a timer in my master page which works perfectly upon first page load. when i switch to another page and the timer disappear. Using the debugger i noticed when changing page the startTimer() is not being called. Note all the code are found in $(document).ready method.The code is working perfectly on localhost but only when the app is deployed that this issue is arising.

```
 function startTimer(duration) {

    var timer = duration;

    var myInterval = setInterval(

        function () {

            try {
                //Will crash beacause IsDirector does not exist
                if (localStorage.getItem("IsDirector") == 1 && TTL == "") {
                    return;
                }

            }

            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);

            }

            try {
                var minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);

                var seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                var display = document.getElementById('LblTimeLeft');

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

                document.getElementById("TimeLefthidden").value = timer;

                localStorage.setItem("TimeLeft", timer);

            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

            if (--timer < 0) {
                //logout user if timeleft is zero
                //removing all session from client browser
                localStorage.clear();

                btnlogout_onclick();

                myStopFunction();
            }


        }, 1000);



};

window.onload = function () {

    startTimer(TTL);
};
```

**Interesting discover**: when i refresh the page the timer doesn't show up(actual error) but if i open developer console and set some breakpoints just for checking some values and close the developer console,the timer appears!!!

Comment: JavaScript is kind of client side script so it should has nothing to do with where is it hosted.  It sounds like when you access the new web page, DOM will not being loaded completely or there was an error on the same page.  Did you get other error message in F12 developer tool when you access new page?

Comment: @JokiesDing no error

Comment: @JokiesDing Please see updated questions